# Jquery Case Sensitive Check

Tags: jquery, case-sensitive

I want to compare a value with a variable ($insurance). If a user input ABC or abc or aBc or abC or something like that.

Then i display a message.

I am using

```
if(($insurance=='ABC') ||($insurance=='abc'){

//my message
```

Is there any way to make that "ABC" case sensitive using jquery?

Comment: Why are you prefixinx your variable with a $ ? That's usually only done for instances of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use a regex :

```
if (/abc/i.test($insurance)){
```

You could also use toLowerCase :

```
if ("abc"===$insurance.toLowerCase()){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLowerCase()` ABC will become abc Abc will become abc etc so you only have to check for `if(text.toLowerCase() == abc)`

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V599a/6/)